# Django REST Framework can't show translatable fields

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-rest-framework, django-hvad

I'm implementing a REST API for a Django-based website using the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) and [Django-hvad](http://django-hvad.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) apps.

Problem: translated fields in REST Viewset cause an error.

> **Please note:** [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801132/django-rest-framework-and-django-hvad) addressed & solved a similar issue, but it does not apply to the app versions I've installed, that
>   is:
>
> 1. Django **1.8**
> 2. hvad **1.2.0**  which has-or rather *claims* to have- builtin support for REST framework, [as explained here](https://django-hvad.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public/restframework.html)
> 3. Django Rest Framework **3.1.1**

Here is my model:

```
class Website(TranslatableModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    default_url = models.URLField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        url = models.URLField(max_length=100, unique=True),
        description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True),
    )
```

And my `urls.py` looks like this (I took the imports out for brevity):

```
# Serializer
class WebsiteSerializer(HyperlinkedTranslatableModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = ('name','default_url','url','description')

# Viewset
class WebsiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Website.objects.language().all()
    serializer_class = WebsiteSerializer

# REST Router
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'websites', WebsiteViewSet)


# URL Patterns
urlpatterns = patterns( '', 
    # ... non translated urls
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',

    url(r'^api/v1/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

With these, the URL `/it/api/v1/websites/` gives the annoying error:

> WrongManager at /it/api/v1/websites/ To access translated fields like
>   'url' from an untranslated model, you must use a translation aware
>   manager. For non-translatable models, you can get one using
>   hvad.utils.get_translation_aware_manager. For translatable models, use
>   the language() method.

**Note**: replacing the `/it` prefix with any other language code doesn't help in any way.

What I've tried so far:

1. in `WebsiteViewSet` class, specifying a fixed argument to the  `language()` function.
2. using a *TranslationMixin* (a language-agnostic serializer exposing all the translations), following the instructions [here](https://django-hvad.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public/restframework.html#translationsmixin). I changed the queryset line like so:
   `queryset = Website.objects.untranslated().prefetch_related('translations').all()`
3. moving the api url definitions outside of the i18n patterns

But in all cases it always gives the very same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks good. So good actually, that copy-pasting it into a blank project seems to be working fine. I put a link to a sample project based on your code and some details on your github issue, could you please try them?

Comment: @spectras yeah, you were right. If you like, you can answer with the above comment and I'll accept the answer. Please feel free to give the github issue reference as a "bonus doc link".